# Django concatenate list queries from two models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As a Django newbie, I am trying to return JSON Objects from two models with each object containing the username, id, ticketID. Right now the code is simply putting the lists together without indexing. I should point out that there is a relationship between user and ticket so that can be traversed also.

{"username":"Paul","id":2}, {"username":"Paul","id":2}, {"username":"Ron","id":19}, {"id":"1c6f039c"}, {"id":"6480e439"},
 {"id":"a97cf1s"}

```
class UsersforEvent(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        value = body['event']
        queryset = Ticket.objects.filter(event = value)
        referenced_users = User.objects.filter(ticket_owner__in=queryset.values('id'))
        result_list = list(itertools.chain(referenced_users.values('username', 'id'), queryset.values('id')))
        return Response((result_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a single query to get the ticket with the related user for each one, then create the list of dicts from there. Assuming your Ticket model has an "owner" field which is a FK to User:

```
queryset = Ticket.objects.filter(event=value).select_related('owner')
result_list = [{'ticket_id': ticket.id, 'username': ticket.owner.username, 'user_id': ticket.owner.id}
               for ticket in queryset]
```

(Note, this shouldn't be the action of a POST though; that is for changing data in the db, not querying.)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, it worked a charm, much appreciated. I will be sure to change the action also like you mentioned.